# WordPress 2nd level subpages

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I have this structure in my WP pages.

```
home
  --submenu
    -- submenu 1
  --submenu
    -- submenu 1
  --submenu
    -- submenu 1
  --submenu
    -- submenu 1
  --submenu
    -- submenu 1
```

how do i get all the submenu 1 items?
 using wp_list_pages?
 i tried using parameter depth =2 but it wont give me the
sub-menu 1 items.

can anybody help me?
any help would be appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submenu 1 items are grandchildren of home and WordPress makes grandchildren hard to deal with for some reason.  So assuming you know the page ID of home, the following code can be adapted to return all of the grandchildren:

http://pastebin.com/drsxdBGY

Comment: thanks for the answer your code seem working but i already find a way of making it...but thans anyways...

Comment: i just noticed something missing in your code<br/><li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li> <br/> $my_query->the_title() should be correct right?